# vimのsyntax regionでstart=+とstart=の違い

Tags: vim

vimでSyntaxファイルを作るときに使う`syntax region`で範囲のパターンを指定するときに
`start=+`のように`=+`を使っているものと`start=`を使っているものがあります。

これらの違いはなんでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h syn-region`でヘルプを見ると、`start=`の部分に「`:syn-pattern`を参照」とあるので参照します。(`:syn-pattern`の何れかの部分にカーソルを移動させて `CTRL-]`を押す)
すると、KiYugadgeterさんの知りたい情報が冒頭に書かれています。

```
    syntaxコマンドでは、パターンの前後を同じ文字で囲まなければならない。これは
    ":s" コマンドと同様である。もっともよく使われるのはダブルクォートである。しか
    しパターンがダブルクォートを含んでいる場合は、そのパターンが含んでいない他の文
    字を使ったほうがよい。
```

Comment: つまり、start="～" の代わりに start=+～+ を使っているだけです。機能的な違いはありません。